# boost serialize compile problems with xml archive

Tags: boost-serialization

The following example compiles only if text file archive is selected. With xml file selection tons of error message lines comes out.

I compile with g++ 4.7.2.

The example contains two times the follwing lines:
boost::archive::xml_oarchive ar(ofs);
boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);

xml did not work
text works

( I only write the same description here so many times, because I could not post with less than 100 lines description here... :-( )

One of the error lines is

```
    /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_iarchive.hpp:70:9: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ boost::serialization::is_wrapper<Base>::************)'
```

Any hint?

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <assert.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>


    #include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/xml_woarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/xml_wiarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

    using namespace std;

    class Base
    {
        public:
            int genericData;

            Base(int _genericData) : genericData(_genericData) {}
            Base() {}

            friend class boost::serialization::access;

            template<typename Archive>
                void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version)
                {
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( genericData );
                }

            virtual void Print() { cout << "Base only " << genericData << endl; }
    };

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base) 

    class A: public Base 
    {
        public: 
            int a;

            A(int _generic, int _a):Base(_generic),a(_a){}
            A(){};

            template<typename Archive>
                void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version)
                {
                    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( a );
                }
            virtual void Print() { cout << "A " << genericData << " " << a << endl; }
    };

    class B: public Base
    {
        public:
            int b1;
            int b2;

            B( int _generic, int _b1, int _b2): Base( _generic), b1(_b1), b2(_b2) {}
            B() {}

            template<typename Archive>
                void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version)
                {
                    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( b1 );
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( b2 );
                }
            virtual void Print() { cout << "B " << genericData << " " << b1 <<  " " << b2 << endl; }
    };

    class C: public Base
    {
        public:
            int c1;
            int c2;
            int c3;

            C( int _generic, int _c1, int _c2, int _c3): Base( _generic), c1(_c1), c2(_c2), c3(_c3) {}
            C() {}

            template<typename Archive>
                void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version)
                {
                    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( c1 );
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( c2 );
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( c3 );
                }
            virtual void Print() { cout << "C " << genericData << " " << c1 <<  " " << c2 << " " << c3 << endl; }
    };

    class Ptr
    {
        public:
            Ptr( Base* _dptr):dptr(_dptr) {}
            Ptr(){}
            Base *dptr;

            template<typename Archive>
                void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) 
                {
                    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(dptr);  // Simply serialize the data members of Obj
                }   

            void Print() 
            {
                cout << "Object Ptr Points to addr: " << dptr << " und enthaelt:" << endl;
                dptr->Print();
            }
    };
    #if 0
    #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID( A, "A");
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID( B, "B");
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID( C, "C");
    #endif

    int main()
    {

        {
            ofstream ofs("test.data");
            boost::archive::xml_oarchive ar(ofs);
            //boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);

            A a( 111, 1);
            B b( 222, 2,20);
            C c( 333, 3,30,300);

            // Base a(1);
            // Base b(2);
            // Base c(3);

            //Ptr p1(&a);
            //Ptr p2(&b);
            //Ptr p3(&c);

            Base *p1( &a);
            Base *p2( &b);
            Base *p3( &c);

            ar.register_type(static_cast<A *>(NULL));
            ar.register_type(static_cast<B *>(NULL));
            ar.register_type(static_cast<C *>(NULL));


            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("dptr",p1);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("dptr",p2);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("dptr",p3);

            p1->Print();
            p2->Print();
            p3->Print();

        }

        cout << "+++" << endl;


        // Read back
        {
            ifstream ifs("test.data");
            boost::archive::xml_iarchive ar(ifs);
            //boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(ifs);

            Base* p1;
            Base* p2;
            Base* p3;

            ar.register_type(static_cast<A *>(NULL));
            ar.register_type(static_cast<B *>(NULL));
            ar.register_type(static_cast<C *>(NULL));

            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("dptr",p1);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("dptr",p2);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("dptr",p3);


            p1->Print();
            p2->Print();
            p3->Print();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That static assertion failure is triggered by these lines:

```
- ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
```

they should be:

```
+ ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base);
```

which exands to:

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp( "Base",
         boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this)
     );
```